# How to boot Ubuntu when external HDD is connected, otherwise boot Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu on my external hard drive and I would like to boot Ubuntu when I plug it in. When it's not plugged, it should boot Windows.

Currently, when my external HDD is not connected, I get to the GNU GRUB version 2.02 screen. Can this be fixed too?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! This could be achieved in the BIOS settings. The particular instructions depend on your hardware/firmware, not an operating system, so the question is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here. You should rather ask on [su]. To remove GRUB from your hard drive, follow [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader).

Comment: If BIOS you just install grub to MBR of external drive and set BIOS to boot external first & Windows second. If UEFI bit more complicated as Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer will only install grub to internal drive and not partition an external with an ESP. So you must partition in advance and include an ESP. Then reconfigure grub after install or see this work around during install. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379