# Dual boot to single boot(SSD and HDD)

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I have installed windows in SSD and linux in HDD.Now I want to delete linux.How can I do it with or without losing data?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI installs. Make sure Windows boots be default first. You can delete the Linux partitions as they are ext4, not NTFS or FAT32. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: Are you asking about data on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to reinstall the Windows bootloader. From that moment on, the machine will directly boot into Windows. See the manual of MS Windows to learn how to reinstall the Windows bootloader.

To free the disk space occupied by the unused linux system, you simply could reformat the Ubuntu partition with a file system supported by MS Windows so you can use it for data storage under Windows. Alternatively, you could repartition the drive. Then, you could delete the Ubuntu partitions and create partitions as you see fit.