# Remove Grub safely

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

a long time ago, I installed GRUB with ubuntu boot loader. Today, I am not using Ubuntu anymore, I came back on Windows 10 (which is my main OS). I saw many tutorials on internet to remove GRUB (and maybe Ubuntu), but I don’t know which one to trust. Can you tell me what to do to simply and safely delete (not just hide/disable/etc...) GRUB from my computer?

Comment: @user535733 i still have windows 10, I don’t nees to reinstall it, and the first step of this tuto is to remove grub, and it is not much explained...

Answer (score 0):

What I did (and it was a really bad idea), is to remove ubuntu partition. Then, at startup, GRUB will show but nothing else happen. So you have to go in boot menu (F12 for my laptop ACER) and boot Windows. Then follow this tutorial [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: So this IS a duplicate. You can mark it as such, so it won't confuse future readers.

Comment: None of the other answers are complete. What if grub was on another disk?