# How do I remove Ubuntu from the BIOS?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bios

So, long story short. I got a new laptop. it had windows and I installed a dual boot with ubuntu. It didn't go as planed and I uninstalled Ubuntu. I deleted the partitions from windows, when I went to check the BIOS Ubuntu option was still there.

Could someone please tell me how to remove Ubuntu from the BIOS? Windows is running fine but I want to get rid of that Ubuntu BIOS option

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think that `bcdedit` may do it. Run it in an admin command prompt window.

Comment: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader