# Forgot to make partition in Win 10 disk managmnt bfor dual booting Ubuntu,Now want to uninstal Ubuntu,But no partition to delete in Win disk mgmt

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, python, uninstall

I dualbooted Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10. I forgot to create partition before installation and just installed and allocated space using "dragging feature". I want to uninstall Ubuntu now, but cannot find any partition in Windows Disk Management, may be because I didnt create one at the beginning(in win disk mgmt).
Actually why i want to uninstall ubuntu now is because i accidentally deleted python which removed all gui,terminal,dashboard etc.
Still how can i uninstall ubuntu now ? as may b later i need to do so

Comment: No need to uninstall, just install new over the old one.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Eagle_Mike thanks, but what if i want to uninstall ubuntu, how will i do it as i see no different partition in windows...

Comment: Windows does not understand the partition format used by Ubuntu. That's why you can't find Ubuntu partition using Windows Disk Management. There is no "uninstall" for Ubuntu, just like you cannot uninstall Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi