# Removed Linux, can't boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I messed around with ubuntu about two years ago then left it, so now I decided to remove it for storage space. Should have known it would not be as easy as select and delete, now my PC won't even boot to the bios. I tried inserting my windows disc, still nothing. What do I do now?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you can just choose Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f12, but varies by vendor. If BIOS you have to reinstall Windows boot loader using your Windows repair disk. Details on UEFI: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: I think it was BIOS. I tried f12, nothing happens, but as I said the PC won't really boot at all, it beeps but stays at a black screen and monitor does not get a signal. How would I use a windows repair disc in this situation?

Comment: Actually the blank screen turned out to be a monitor issue that conveniently happened right on this time, just had to unplug it for a minute and plug it back in, now I actually see my bios. Proceeding as planned.