# I tried to uninstall ubuntu from dual-boot drive and install it on the new one. I failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I followed instructions for uninstalling ubuntu from windows and repairing boot manager using windows USB Drive.

Repairing the boot manager didn't work, so I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888). It helped and now windows boots normally.

After this, I went on with a new installation of ubuntu. I hoped it would install new grub and everything will be fine, but still my computer boots to windows.

Also, the strange thing is that the new hard drive doesn't show up in boot order in UEFI.

I know I am missing something.

Could you Please help me?

I can't find proper answer in their Internet regarding ”uninstallation of ubuntu -> proceeding to new installation”. Almost all tutorials help you never come back to ubuntu

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues. So post link and someone should see it that default fix is best or perhaps something else.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred right now I tried to reset UEFI to defaults and finally during ubuntu installation there was an option to install along with windows boot manager. I hope it will solve everything. I guess that sometimes the most straightforward solutions are the best. We will see in a few minutes

Comment: Yup, now it works. After the installation, I had just to change boot hard drives priority. That's cool