# Will removing Ubuntu remove grub or not?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am installing Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows 10) on my laptop and I wanted to know if I format the partition in which Ubuntu is installed, will Grub bootloader be removed too? If not then how can I recover the Windows bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not be removed. There are 3 ways to recover windows boot manager.

1. Remove grub by using the command prompt as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/1073514).

> **This answer is for those with UEFI who have deleted the Ubuntu partitions before removing grub**
>
> You will be doing this from Windows 10. No bootable media required.
>
> Where `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootsect /nt60` and the Ubuntu live with the
>   `boot-repair` suggestions have failed, this has worked for me:
>
> (This answer borrowed verbatim from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/1073514))
>
> 1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
> 2. Run `diskpart`
> 3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
> 4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk (the EFI volume will be formatted in FAT, others will be NTFS)
> 5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
> 6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
> 7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
> 8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
> 9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
> 10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
> 11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
> 12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory
>
> Assuming you only ever had two operating systems (Win 10 & Ubuntu) you
>   should now be able to boot directly to Windows without hitting the
>   black grub screen.
>
> [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/1073514):
>   http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/

2. Bot into Windows installation media USB and run `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` in Repair your computer=> Troubleshoot=> Advanced=> Command Prompt. See [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/).
3. You can "Hide" the grub by moving `Windows boot manager` above Ubuntu in Boot sequence in firmware settings.