# Reinstall GRUB bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu, grubrescue

I'm new to this forum, but I needed to ask a question. How do I reinstall the GRUB bootloader? Since I'm new, I didn't knew that I couldn't simply delete the partition from windows and add the unused space. I needed to delete the lubuntu installation, to install Xubuntu. But I didn't knew I also needed to delete the bootloader, since as I said, I'm new to linux. So I tried to boot into Windows 7, and I see the screen of
`error: no such partition`
`entering rescue mode`
And then it drops me into rescue mode. Now, I made a Lubuntu Installation USB in hope to reinstall the GRUB bootloader by just installing Lubuntu. But guess what. The installer fails to shrink the partition. I tried sudo --bind but it says: `mount point doesn't exist`. Any help will be appreciated. And I cannot, and repeat **cannot**, and again, *cannot* delete the windows partition, cause the laptop isn't mine, but of my dad so without his permission I cannot delete the win7 partition.

Comment: Do you have your Lubuntu or Xubuntu installer on a bootable USB drive?

Comment: FYI: Your issue is not specific to Lubuntu/Linux; the problem is you had `grub` (a GNU program that selects which OS you want to use) control your booting; it has a pointer in the MBR & it's code existed in /boot/grub/ of a partition. You needed to correct the MBR first (windows has a command that will do that) before you deleted the partition it pointed to, or you're stuck with a *dangling* point to nowhere. It would have occurred if windows controlled booting (with it's version of grub) and you deleted windows from within Lubuntu. Your windows 7 recovery media can correct this.

Comment: If you'd installed Xubuntu over Lubuntu; the issue would not have occurred either; Xubuntu would have just overwritten the Lubuntu pointer with it's own (just as a fresh windows install would too). It also helps if you provide specifics (release details; Lubuntu installer varies on release).  If you use commands you can `chainloader` to your existing windows 7 to get it booted, then enter the command you incorrectly missed the first time to have it own & handle booting of your system (`bootrec`)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If it does not solve your problem automatically, please [edit] your question to include the Boot-Info URL generated by Boot-Repair. Or if you only want to keep Windows, see [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/q/429610/250300).

Comment: Note that `boot-repair` must be run from a live session.  Don't try to run `boot-repair` from your installed OS.

Answer (score 0):

Whats problem with free space? Delete all not system partitions, I mean you have 1 or 2 (reserved) system partitions, boot Linux installation. To avoid confusion in graphical markup, create a partition with fdisk.

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdX` - where X you hard drive, the laptop most likely has one hard drive (/dev/sda). To view all disks run `sudo fdisk -l`
Then create partitions for Linux:
type n to create new partition -> first sector default -> for last sector type +50GB to make root. If you have UEFI, create 512MB partition: enter t for change type, l - to view list, enter code for "EFI Partition". To write changes enter w.
Next, `mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdxY`, where sdY is EFI partition.

In installer also set efi mount point for this partition. After installation, just in case, run os-prober.

If something doesn't work out, welcome to wiki
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: "Partition only in read mode"