# Can't install dual boot Windows 10- Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I wanted a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I partition the ssd of my laptop, installed both and everything worked fine. Then, for school reasons, I needed Ubuntu 18.04, so I deleted the partition where Ubuntu 20.04 was, and because when I booted my laptop in the grub it still appeared both the entry for Ubuntu and Windows (even though Ubuntu 20.04 was deleted), I followed the steps of the first answer of this post:

[Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/429653#429653?newreg=a60e122899004f26a18da51cde0b1f1a)

That basically said to go to my efi partition and there deleted the ubuntu directory. It worked and when I boot my laptop it runs Windows 10. Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS on a virtual machine, but again, for school reasons, I need native Ubuntu 18.04LTS on my laptop. So I made a stick with Ubuntu 18.04LTS (using Rufus) and tried to install it, but when I boot the stick, it shows me this:

[image]

and then takes me to the gnu grub prompt. And I don't know what to do. Windows 10 works just fine. I guess maybe I need to create another directory similar to the one I deleted before..? I appreciate your help.

Thank you for you time!

PD: english is not my first language, so I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug your USB stick with Ubuntu 18.04LTS installer, and it still loads Grub from your hard drive, you most likely have to change the boot order in the BIOS.

Check how to enter BIOS configuration, possibly hitting F8 or F12 before booting.
That is often posted in a legend on screen.

Comment: I already did that. If I don't boot the Ubuntu 18.04LTS stick, it runs Windows.

Comment: @MrCrowley - Then I do not understand what is the sequence of steps you are trying, and what is the result you get. If you could edit the OP to be more specific, I guess it would help.

Comment: I edited the post, I hope it makes more sense now. Thank you for your time!