# Ubuntu 20.04 Windows 10 not detected in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

Hy, So i have a issue with the dual boot windows 10 is not detected & i tried the boot repair here is what it say

"LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB)."

adding that i can't boot anymore to the windows with the bios, its says

"this is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floopy press any key to try again"

tried to do with the 40_custom , but it say EFI FILE PATH ERROR

Thankss :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you installed Ubuntu in a different mode than Windows.
If your device came pre-installed with Windows, I will assume it was installed using EFI mode, with fast startup enabled.

You will need to first make your Windows installation work (i.e. boot) again, then re-install Ubuntu using the same installation mode as Windows.

To do that, boot into your BIOS and change boot order, so "Windows Boot Loader" is the first. If you changed from EFI boot to legacy, change it back. If you disabled fast startup you may need to re-enable it (not necessarily, some installations will work regardless).

Once Windows is working, remove Ubuntu completely, by deleting the partition completely, and then [remove grub from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader) boot loader.

When you are done with that, re-install Ubuntu using the same installation mode as Windows.

Note: you will need to use partition editing techniques and other methods that require some understanding and experience. Only follow the above suggestion if you know how to use these tools.

Comment: Hello ,thank you for your reply. i can no longer boot on windows its says " This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floopy press any key to try again ..."

Comment: OK, so this may be a little bit more complicated than that. Do you have access to Windows Installation Media?

Comment: (saved too soon)  Get [Windows installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).  Use the installation media, to get to the repair console. Then use DiskPart to list the partitions and make sure the Windows OS partition is set to active.  Another option is to use your live Linux USB and install gparted (sudo apt install gparted) to check the partitions. You can post screenshots of the results, if you need help figuring it out.  Also, check [this guide](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/).

Comment: i reinstalled the ubuntu with bios mode & its work actually thank you.