# How do I remove just Ubuntu OS from my PC

Tags: uninstall

I have two OS installed on my PC:

1. Ubuntu 20.10
2. Elementary OS

Now I want to remove Ubuntu completely and keep Elementary OS.

How do I do that?
Please help

Comment: Which operating system "owns" GRUB?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to find that out. Could you please help me with that. I would really appreciate it

Comment: Grub default will be first in grub menu. So is that Ubuntu and you have to scroll down for Elementary? You should be able to reset Elementary as default, but different if UEFI or BIOS installs.  If UEFI: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: I checked in GRUB. Elementary OS "owns" it.

Comment: So next what do I do.

Comment: Make sure your backups are in order.  Delete the partition with Ubuntu and run `update-grub` in ElementaryOS.