# how to remove GRUB after removing the linux?

Tags: windows-10, grubrescue

I had removed my linux from my system but had not removed GRUB.Everytime i power on my laptop i have to type exit to load up windows.I am unable to find a proper fix for this i have **windows 10 Home**.How can i remove **GRUB** and boot directly to my windows?

Comment: You can change UEFI boot order in UEFI settings menu and boot tab. But should delete Ubuntu entry in UEFI and /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP. See details: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have deleted all the partitions linux was in (if you haven't you can do it from windows later) you will need to make the windows bootloader the standard, the easiest way of doing this is with windows itself, you should make a new windows recovery usb, and then use it to repair the bootloader.

You should boot your system from the recovery usb (the way to do this depends on your particular system) and then do the following:

1. Click on the Repair your Computer link at the bottom of the Install Now screen.
2. Click on Troubleshoot
3. Select Command Prompt
4. Enter the following three commands in turn, following each by pressing the Enter key:

```
    bootrec /fixmbr
    bootrec /fixboot
    bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

5. Restart the PC with the installation media removed to check if the repair worked

source: https://www.dell.com/support/article/es-uy/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: yeah i will give it a try but i font have windows recovery usb

Comment: you can create one yourself, see [this Microsoft instructive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-recovery-drive-abb4691b-5324-6d4a-8766-73fab304c246) . (you don't necesarily need to do it from the same computer, if you search you'll find how to do it from another pc)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the entire partition that you had installed linux on it or just forms=at it. Windows partition will be safe and you have deleted linux

Comment: This may not work on all laptops

Comment: May work. Never mind

Comment: i formatted the entire partition only but still its there.

Comment: Rakshith baskar sorry to hear that. It wirked for me. I think you have chosen the entire disk while installing ubuntu for boot loader that is the reason

Comment: i let Ubuntu handle the installation.

Comment: I know. That is  the default option. When you choose no partition it chooses the entire partition.