# Remove ubuntu if installed in laptop by dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I have just dual boot, (win 10 + ubuntu 18.4)
**using these steps** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1ykDpSzpKU`

windows 10 was already installed in my laptop, alongside i tried to install ubuntu 18.4
i followed all steps , i saw restart now option i clicked it. & error appeared

I restarted system & no ubuntu grub appeared, it continued with windows 10

**How can i check if that setup is installed in system ?**
I want to remove it as it disturbs my windows setup
it became slow in booting.

Any help please.

Thankyou

Comment: Thanks, i have updated.

Comment: It is unclear what steps were followed.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: i used this steps - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1ykDpSzpKU

Comment: ...related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: You have to make sure Windows is reset to default boot in UEFI, first. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: I just deleted the space that i have alloted to Ubuntu installation from windows disk management

Comment: From windows i can see my disks have data (free space). And it seems accurate. So it seems like Ubuntu is removed. As i have formatted the disk space which i had allotted to Ubuntu and extended that space by creating a new disk drive. The only thing that bother me little in my laptop is, when i    start it it use to take 30 seconds but now it takes upto 45 seconds. I am not sure why.