# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 from usb. HP UEFI laptop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04

What are the most **important partitions** (in **"Something else"** installation) when i want to **dual boot** ubuntu **20.04** and **windows 10** ?.
My pc info:
Boot type = **UEFI** ,
Laptop name = **HP**

Comment: You cannot boot Windows installed on external drive. Grub will boot internal drive's installs, if fast start up off. The ESP - efi system partition & / (root) are required. Many want separate /home and/or data partition(s). UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: @oldfred: You can install Windows-to-Go on an external drive, even on a USB flash drive, You can then install Ubuntu next to it on the same drive. Rufus will install WtG, I think Universal will too. I can find no difference between Windows and WtG.

Comment: It looks like Windows-to-Go is being discontinued. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go And it was for Enterprise (or Education) versions.