# How can I store FULL Ubuntu on a flash drive?

Tags: live-usb

So I want to store full Ubuntu on a flash drive so when I plug in the flash drive in a computer with the BIOS edited full Ubuntu starts up. I already have a bootable USB 32GB with and i know how to start it. I don't want the live version. I don't have too much experience with Linux.

Comment: Yes, you can install Ubuntu to a USB flash drive.  What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: If UEFI, you need to partition in advance to have the ESP - efi system partition on external (or any second drive).  External drives boot from drive entry (just like flash drive installer) not the internal drive's "ubuntu" entry. This applies to all second drives. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: Here is a simple method of making a Full install USB that boots both BIOS and UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi/1300458#1300458