# Ubuntu install dual boot with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

So, I have the following scenario:
Two SSDs, in one I have windows 10 installed in the other one I have the Ubuntu(20.04.1) installed. As a tutorial I used something similar: https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-with-windows-10-in-dual-boot/. The only difference is that I never had the option install alongside windows or windows boot manager.
Installation of Ubuntu was done using the "**something else**" route, formatted the second SSD, one partition(only "/" -> simplicity).
Now, I have two questions:

1. Using the previous installation, It seems I cannot see the menu where one can choose the OS. My assumtion is that grub was not properly updated. How can I fix this without damaging Windows 10?
   Is `sudo update-grub` sufficent?
   I verified if it is installed properly by clicking f12 during reboot, the second ssd was shown and I could boot into Ubuntu. All good there, only issue is that is not shown in the boot menu.
2. If let's say in the future I have the same scenario - install Ubuntu after windows 10(different SSDs or any hard drives), is there a way to install it properly from the beginning? -> meaning I can see the menu every time the computer starts.
   thanks.

Comment: You have to install both in UEFI boot mode if newer system. And best to disconnect or in UEFI turn off/disable other drive when installing system. Then no issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks. Let's make a summary. First I have to disable the other SSD from bios. Will have to check how to do that as I cannot just unplug it as it is directly from motherboard as it is attached directly in one of the m2 places(I would like to do that as a last resort). I install it via UEFi Mode(When it boots I see an option UEFI mode sandisk -> sandisk is my usb). I choose that one and proceed with the installation. Now, after that it is a bit unclear to be how I fix grub menu. Your last messages were not so clear.

Comment: If both installed in same boot mode it is just `sudo update-grub` which is run with kernel updates & some support software. Boot-Repair also runs it with its repairs, but usually reinstall grub. But best to review what Boot-Repair is doing, and sometimes only its advanced mode reinstalls grub correctly. My motherboard has a way to disable drive. Link shows other alternatives. I have always used the unmount of ESP & mount of correct ESP in middle of install and that works. Mounts in Something Else not shown until about the screen for adding username & password. I just also have terminal open.