# Install Ubuntu including the bootloader on second drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

I know this question was often asked before and I have tried all the steps from the answers, but when I want to install Ubuntu (I tried 20.10 LTS and 18.04 LTS) on my system, which runs windows on the primary drive, the bootloader gets always installed on the drive where the windows bootloader sits.

It worked with Kali and it was working some time ago, I don't know what changed.

I started Ubuntu via a live stick and pressed install Ubuntu, after that I went to something else, created the root partition and selected the desired drive as the Bootloader installation location. After the successful install the bios shows me, that the bootloader was installed in my Windows drive.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You have to partition in advance & include an ESP - efi system partition on sdb. Multiiple work arounds. And post to old bug report. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153
Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Read the Wikipedia pages for "`POST`", "`MBR`", "`UEFI`", "`BIOS`". Together, they'll help you understand what's what.