# How to properly dual-boot in seperate drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, ssd

I've got my Windows 10 in my main drive and want to boot ubuntu in my SSD, but the problem is when I set up Ubuntu, no matter how I do it, something is apparently is wrong and I either keep booting into Windows(even when I choose ubuntu from BIOS) or ubuntu wants me to keep re-installing.

I use rufus with UEFI, my BIOS setting is set to UEFI, fast boot is disabled, I make a partition of SSD.

First one happens if I set up the whole thing in SSD and the second one if I try set up the boot alongside Windows, this seems silly and doesn't work but atleast managed to have another boot option than Windows.
So my question is, what's the best method to make this possible?

Comment: What brand/model system? Did you partition in advance? Or is having grub2's efiboot loader in Windows ESP ok? Some what grub on Ubuntu drive. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: @oldfred http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p5b8Y2HV84/, I did partition, I am using a lenovo 520s-14ikb, I didn't understant your question about efiboot loaged in Windows ESP.

Comment: Ubiquity installs grub to first drive's ESP, usually Windows ESP. But in your case it saw the NVMe drive and installed to it. But NVMe drive is MBR. UEFI recommends gpt, Windows requires gpt, but Ubuntu will let you use MBR for UEFI install, and probably should not. It will work, but if you want better gpt over MBR, now is time to change.  Can you boot Ubuntu entry in UEFI menu. You also show old BIOS boot loaders in MBRs, do not attempt to boot in BIOS/legacy/CSM mode or it will try to use those and fail.  Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: Dual-drive vs. a Dual-boot menu selection.

This 'should' pose no risk to your win10 data but, just in case, back everything up before anything else!

---

So,

If you are using two physical drives (1 hdd + 1 ssd) then I would go as far as:

> Temporarily remove the physical windows hdd and set aside.
> Mount the ssd into the primary drive slot.
> Run the Ubuntu install on the ssd as a primary drive.

1 partition (if you want only one) & 100% Ubuntu. Personally I use a dually accessable partition as my storage, formatted as NTFS. My Ubuntu partition is "ext4".
Thus: Ubuntu can: also access my storage partition as well as the windows partition. But, windows can: ONLY also access the storage partition.

Why? I don't want/need microsnoooop being able to access any data in/on my primary OS. (Call me paraniod but I been in the game since the trs-80 days) And, using a memory stick is just too darned slow!!

Anyhoooo... Once your Ubuntu install is finished you can put the win/hdd back into the computer.

Here I would decide which system I will use more... Ubuntu/ssd?(!) Then I would place the win/hdd into the secondary drive slot. (me = single ssd laptop. Ubuntu is my primary partition & preferred OS... the win10 partition is only there for the hell of it ;)

After this, you can choose which drive to boot from in the BIOS (and in which order). And if you did't know, during POST you can also select a temporary boot... In my Dell it is "f12"... hit that the same time you would hit "f2" (or whatever you use to get into your BIOS settings). This will let you choose what device you want to boot from right then. (ie. USB, CD, SSD, HDD, etc...) I vaguely recall 'f10' on one system... and that one is probably still sitting in the cellar! HEH!

_______ Hope this helps and Good luck!

Peace............