# Installing Xubuntu on another SDD - can I install on an external hard drive then if the installation is successful move it internally?

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, ssd

I need to upgrade the SSD in my home-server, from a 128GB to a 512GB. I also want to re-install the system instead of cloning, so that I can start from scratch.

I purchased the new SSD and an external USB3 case for it.

The process I had in mind was to save the data I need to save, remove the 128G SSD and replacing it with the 512G (only one slot in computer). Then boot with a USB flash drive and reinstall Xubuntu to the new hard drive.

But I thought maybe I can connect the new drive (with the USB case) to the computer and install everything there - then once I verify the installation works I can perform the actual switch of SSD inside the computer.

Which one of the two methods would you recommend and why? Or would you do differently altogether?

PS - not sure if it has any impact but the computer is a Dell OptiPlex 3070 Micro with UEFI and secure boot. Does this change anything?

thank you for any input.

Comment: Ubuntu will install its boot loader to the first drive's ESP usually the internal drive. So your install to external may not even have an ESP, nor the boot files. I think easier to install when drive is internal. Use gpt partitioning, if you partition in advance. Default install boots from 'ubuntu' entry, but correct install to external drive boots from a drive entry like live installer. You can install to external with one of these work arounds: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: You should have no problems installing Xubuntu on external SSD and then using that SSD internally or on other computers. I always prefer removing my internal drive before making a Full install of Ubuntu to another drive, sometimes I make mistakes. The Ubuntu install should be made in the same Legacy/UEFI mode that any other OS on the computer are installed with so that GRUB will work.