# How to have full Ubuntu on USB disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, system-installation, usb

I am new to use Linux, so sorry for this stupid question.
I've try to have Full Ubuntu on my USB(it is 64GB), I've did it by this tutorial: https://www.fosslinux.com/10212/how-to-install-a-complete-ubuntu-on-a-usb-flash-drive.htm , but when it writes it is complete to restart PC and remove my USB with installation medium(I've got another USB stick, 4GB which I used with rufus to boot Ubuntu), so now I my PC I've got plugged only the 64GB with installed Ubuntu, but when I open Boot menu, only Windows boot option will show there.
I will be very grateful for all the answers and have a nice day.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up booting from USB in your BIOS. So maybe this really isn't about Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu installer Ubiquity only installs grub boot loader to internal drive's ESP. if UEFI. You have to reinstall grub, if you did not do one of these work arounds. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 If BIOS/MBR, you have to have selected to install grub to flash drive (that selection does not work with UEFI), All external drives boot from a USB drive entry not "ubuntu" like internal drive.

Comment: Lots wrong with those instructions. No EFI boot partition so it will only boot BIOS, Minimum size of ext4 root partition is 8GB, not 4GB. For a first time Full install to USB device that boots BIOS and UEFI, I would recommend an image flash as shown here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi There is very little that can go wrong with this method.

Comment: @Artur Meinild: Don't you think that if the OP can boot a Rufus USB in his computer, that his computer BIOS is already set up for booting USB?

Answer (score 0):

I would think when you check your machine is booting `EFI` only in your firmware. That guide gets you to set it up as a `MBR` boot device. Without the supposed to be about 100-200MB in size `FAT` partition at the start marked as type`EFI System Partition` it will never boot on an `EFI` or show in the menu on such a system. The files that are supposed to be installed in that partition are not done when in `MBR` mode type for the installer. It needs to boot in such a way too but since it booted for the install on `EFI` machine it must be doing that so it is the missing partition type causing it. I never read all of it, does he have you make the large fat for a swap area? Thus making certain you kill off the drive earlier with all the wear that causes. To fix it do an install where you make the tiny `FAT` at the start and select it in that page for use as system partition however it is worded. Then once done it will be an `EFI` install. When looking around in the `BIOS/Firmware` there may be setting for `CSM mode` or to use both you can try this option to see if it boots the Ubuntu and will still allow Windows to boot with it enabled too.