# How do I choose where to install the bootloader?

Tags: boot

When I changed the device where to install the bootloader and I went to give OK the button did nothing. What can I do to solve this?

---

*Original (Spanish):*

> **Pq cuando estaba instalando Ubuntu 20.04 me salio un cartel q
> me decía q la instalación del gestor de arranque fallo**
>
> Cuando cambie el dispositivo donde instalar el gestor de arranque y
> fui a dar ok el botón no hacía nada. Que puedo hacer para solucionar
> esto?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to understand your problem.  Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1352075/edit) to provide more details and context.  You should tell us what version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using.  You should also include more information about the current state of your installation.  Is Ubuntu already installed?  Are you trying to install Ubuntu for the first time?  You should also provide more information about your hardware and tell us if there are any other operating systems installed.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is really only supported in [English](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1506/what-to-do-with-non-english-questions-or-answers).  You can post in another language, but you are much more likely to get an answer if you post in English.  Question titles should be in English, because question titles are how our site is organized. Consider using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) to improve your chances of getting a response.

Comment: If UEFI install, choice does not work. It only installs to ESP - efi system partition on first device. If two drives: Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153