# Installing ubuntu on a parition with usb installation

Tags: partitioning, bootloader, usb-installation

i have a main windows drive which is full and a 2tb drive which i use for my high storage apps/games, I partitiond 600gb of my 2tb drive which i chose as the location to install ubuntu, on ubuntu installation what device do i use for my boot loader installation.

Comment: Is Windows UEFI? And HDD, gpt partitioned? Only use Something Else install option, but choice of boot loader location only works with BIOS/MBR installs. If UEFI, you want an UEFI install.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: I would unplug your Windows drive and then install to the 2TB drive in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows is installed in. After install plug in Windows and run `sudo update-grub` to add windows to the Ubuntu boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

- Open command prompt
- Type `diskpart`
- In the new window type `list disk`
- Identify your 2tb drive
- For example let your 2tb drive be disk 1
- Type `select disk 1`
- Type `list vol` (vol means volume present in the selected disk)
- Now check for the 600gb volume. Just check the space and you can.

Still if you can't then format the volume to any another type which is not being displayed like fat32. With that you may identify the volume then check where it says it's location

Try using the disk manager of windows.

If you wanted to learn how to boot from live usb then use BIOS/UEFI and make sure that Boot from external device is on and the priority is first.