# Trying installing Ubuntu along-side of Windows 10 UEFI in a separe disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I would like to install Ubuntu on my computer in Dual Boot on a separate disk.

I have 3 discs:

1. C: System
2. D: Documents
3. F: New disk (where I want to install Ubuntu)

My Windows 10 is installed on UEFI

I already have a bootable pen

But when I access the Bios of my Motherboard A320M granade,
There are two bootable pens there. You're both the same but one has UEFI and the other doesn't

I've already tried the one that doesn't have
And then almost finished, the list of systems appeared. Ubuntu started well. But Windows 10 doesn't. When I started Windows 10 the following message appeared "Your pc needs repair"

So I had to change the boot order and boot into Windows 10 and format the Ubuntu disk back to normal...

But I still don't have Ubuntu!

I do not know what to do!

Comment: If you expect to dual boot then both need to use UEFI. It is that simple. Turn off all windows features like fast boot secure boot and bit locker.

Comment: I suggest you read this before you try again. https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/

Comment: Did you make any change inside your BIOS?

Comment: See this now very old bug, it also has several work arounds: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Then use Something Else instlall option to choose ESP, / (root), and /home if you want that also as separate partition.