# Dual Boot (Win10 & Ubuntu20.04) on 2 Hard drives - Grub problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have some problems setting up a dual boot between Win10 and Ubuntu20.04.
To be specific, it seems the bootloader grub doesn't find my second hard drive.
Note: I've added some pictures at the bottom.

**My setup:**

- Microsoft Surface Pro (2017) with internal SSD (256GB)
- SanDisk - High Endurance MicroSD-Card (128GB)

**My Plan:**
Set up a dual boot with Win10 on the internal SSD and Ubuntu on the added MicroSD-Card.

**What I did:**
Note: I've tried to install Ubuntu serveral times now and always ended up with the same grub-problem.

- I used "rufus" to create a bootable USB-Stick. I made sure that UEFI is enabled. (pic. 1)
- I disabled "fast-boot" in Win10 and "Secure-boot" in UEFI
- I booted with the USB-Stick, went into live-mode and installed Ubuntu. On my...

  - ...fist try I chose "Install  Ubuntu alongside Win10".
  - ...second try I chose "something different" and partitioned the drive myself (like in the answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)).
  - ...third try (**current state**) I chose "erase disk".
    Every time the installation went well, but not once I could boot normally.

**My Problem:**
When I restart after installation I always end up in the "grub bash like" terminal (pic. 2).
I read in a tutorial that I have to tell grub where my "root" is, but when i type "ls", the second Hard drive (MicroSD-Card) doesn't even show up.
When I type "exit", Win10 boots normally. When I reboot, enter UEFI and tell it to boot into Ubuntu directly, it works (pic. 3&4).
But on every "normal" boot, it sends me to the grub terminal.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried different installation methods (no difference)
- I've tried using the Boot-Repair tool. No effect.

I've had the same problem a year ago with my main Desktop-PC (I also used a separate SSD for Linux) and had the exact same Problem.
Last time I surrendered. This time I want to find a solution.

**Pictures:**

1. Rufus - Bootable USB-Stick
2. [Grub2 - Bash like terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikStC.jpg)
3. UEFI - Boot-configuration
4. [Grub2 - Boot-menue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBqh0.jpg)

**Edit 1:**
I tried boot-repair again, this time in advanced mode. These were the settings (those were default)

- [Main options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHiV2.png)
- [location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzuL.png)

The returned Summaries:

- [Info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fGqDyymkCv/)
- [Repair](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YFPw7W5vgP/)

Here is a [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9dRp.png) of the partitions in GParted

*New Problem: Now I can't even boot manually into Ubuntu via UEFI anymore. The entry is still there but if i chose "boot with ubuntu" the screen goes dark for 2 sec. and I end up in UEFI again.*

Note: I had to delete some pictures because i can only incluse 8 Links.

Comment: Is Windows fast startup off? Have you updated both UEFI & SSD firmware? Do you have an ESP on flash drive? Or is Ubuntu boot loader in ESP on SSD? Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator  UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Hi Oldfred, yes fast startup is off. Grub should be on the ESP of the MicroSD card. I looked at your post of your first link and tried boot-repair in advaced mode. I'll edit my post with the pictures of the settings and a link. But now i cant even boot manually via UEFI into linux anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how or where to upload the summary report from boot repair. What do you usually use on askUbuntu?

Comment: In Boot-Repair you just click to run Create Bootinfo Summary report & it will offer to upload to pastebin site. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Alright, I added the Links below the settings for Boot-repair.

Comment: Have you tried turning UEFI Secure Boot off?

Comment: Yes i have.
Currently I'm trying to follow this guide: https://blog.hackdesk.com/running-ubuntu-on-micro-sd-card-on-surface-pro-4-dfe9e38e17e1

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub to first drive's ESP. To have grub on SD card, you have to do a work around or use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. Old, still valid: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079

Comment: You're probably right but boot-repair didn't work for me. Last time it crashed grub and I couldn't boot manually into Ubuntu anymore.
In the solution I posted, I copied the efi partition of the first drive into the efi partition of  the SD-card. Looks like it does the job.

Comment: You probably should update fstab entry with UUID of ESP on SD card, not UUID of internal drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for your suggestions!
I found a solution:

I followed (mostly) this [guide](https://blog.hackdesk.com/running-ubuntu-on-micro-sd-card-on-surface-pro-4-dfe9e38e17e1). I changed:

- Step 21: I've chosen "erase disk and install ubuntu"
- Step 22&23: Choose the SD-Card
- before Step 28: check the names of your drives with "sudo fdisk -l" (see Zhihao Wu's [Comment](https://medium.com/@zhihaowu208/thank-you-for-writing-this-comprehensive-tutorial-6588e4e0cdf))
- Step 30: Don't drag "ubuntu" to the top (See MegaKyurem's [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/9lrf6e/how_do_i_dual_boot_from_a_micro_sd_card_on_a/)). My Boot-order is: **USB** - Ubuntu - Windows

Reboot and it should work!
You can even turn "secure boot" in UEFI back on (if you don't want the read lock to appear on your boot-screen).

Answer (score 2):

you probably cannot select the sd card as a boot medium (like usb,cd or lan) in your bios.
if not available for boot i don't think you can use it for an os.

you might stick the sd card in a usb card reader and see if a default dual boot install or boot-repair will work.

Comment: I thought so too but:
- ... I had the same problem a year ago with a normal SSD
- ... I can boot direclty into Linux but just if I juse the detour through UEFI 
(Picture 3: select Ubuntu, hit enter -> boots normaly)

Comment: at that point the sd card reader might have become active.

Comment: From a quick Google web search. It is a jungle. If you are lucky, you can boot from an SD card with your current devices. You create an SD boot drive like you install a USB boot drive, for example with mkusb in linux and with Rufus or Win32 Disk Imager in Windows Also read this site. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD

Comment: I figured it out. The Surface Pro 2017 (5) can definitely boot from MicroSD-Card. But it is important that "USB" is the first entry in the boot-order (see my answer that I posted).

Comment: Regardless of whether this answer helped the user in the end, I think this is a good first answer with a helpful workaround suggestion and may help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of Microsoft Surface Pro you have. Model 3 can boot from SD, model 4 doesn't. Please take a look at he Microsoft Community. e.g. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-4-boot-from-sd-card/b0eeb516-50b3-4460-8492-6ebb4edd9648. It seems to be able to boot from USB. Maybe a USB-SD cardreader is an option. I'm not sure though. Boot from USB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/boot-surface-from-a-usb-device-fe7a7323-8d1d-823d-be17-9aec89c4f9f5.