# How to move grub from sda to sdb?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, grub2

I've tried other solutions I found online (including here), and none of them worked, and looks like no 1 has an answer for what is seemingly supposed to be a simple thing to do.

If you have the answer please guide me completely with specific commands because I will not be able to do it alone, I am not that high level in Linux/Ubuntu.

I have 2 SSDs:

- First is a 250GB SSD with only Windows 10 installed on it.
- Second is a 500GB SSD originally installed with Windows 10. Then I shrank 200GB of it for Ubuntu (20.04).

I specified the boot drive during installation to be sdb, which is the 500GB, but it still installed GRUB inside sda1(/boot/efi) partition, alongside Windows Boot Manager of sda.

Using GPT

I tried the grub-install method (grub-install /dev/sdb) - it showed some output in terminal, but after the restart, the situation is the same: the boot partition remains in sda with GRUB in it.

How can I move GRUB to the correct partition on sdb? Either alongside Windows Boot Manager of sdb (as it is now with sda), or maybe on a different partition on sdb.

I do not want to physically unplug the 250GB and then install Ubuntu, I want to solve it in a way that won't make me open the PC case every time I want to format my PC

Comment: Is install UEFI, so then do you have an ESP - efi system partiiton on sdb. Ubuntu's Ubiquity will only install grub to first drive. Just reinstall grub use Boot-Repair, but have to change fstab to UUID of ESP on sdb. Or if new install see this for several work arounds: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 and more details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079

Comment: @user68186 no because I do not want to unplug drives

Comment: Does your bios support booting from sdb?  If not, you can't move grub there.

Comment: I can boot from either of the SSD's Windows Boot Managers (But not sure if it's the same)

Comment: Is't this a matter of reinstalling grub, but select the other drive to install to?

Comment: @vanadium It may be possible to reinstall grub in a newly created EFI System Partition (ESP) in the correct drive. But one will have to create the partition first. After reinstalling grub one should also delete the parts of grub in the old ESP in the drive with Windows.

Comment: @user68186 this is only for pre-installation, I already installed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was caused by a [longstanding bug in Ubiquity.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379) In brief, Ubiquity (the Ubuntu Desktop installer) ignores the specification of the disk to which GRUB should install when you install in EFI mode. That information won't really help you fix the problem, but it's worth knowing. There are a couple of ways of changing your boot disk as you want....

### The Easy Solution

The [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) should be able to do this semi-automatically. It's been a while since I've used Boot Repair, so I can't provide step-by-step instructions, but it should be able to install GRUB 2 on your `/dev/sdb`. I'm not 100% sure that it will change what's mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu, though. It may also fail if your `/dev/sdb` doesn't have an ESP or if the tool runs into any other unexpected pitfalls.

### The Hard Solution

To solve the problem manually, you should first verify that your `/dev/sdb` has an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) This is easily done with various partitioning tools; for instance, with `gdisk`, you'd list the partitions and look for a partition with a type code of `EF00`:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 15628053168 sectors, 7.3 TiB
Model: TOSHIBA HDWF180 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): A29BEED8-295E-48F3-A7E5-2C1C669A0226
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15628053134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1128447   550.0 MiB   EF00  Unused ESP
   2         1128448         3225599   1024.0 MiB  8300  Unused /boot
   3         3225600     15628053134   7.3 TiB     8E00  Linux LVM
```

This example is taken from one of my computers, and it shows an ESP on `/dev/sdb1` with the name `Unused ESP`. Yours likely would not have that name. If you see an ESP, you should double-check that it has a FAT filesystem with the `blkid` utility:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Unused ESP" PARTUUID="94c47102a617-4224-9f29-5779220d4b7f"
```

This example shows that the partition has no filesystem -- they're normally explicitly identified, as in this example on the same computer:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="NVME_SSD" LABEL="NVME_SSD" UUID="6CB1-160F" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="5f63fbfe-1a11-4ed8-80ff-13f1df6f04c0"
```

Note the `TYPE="vfat"` description in this case; this ESP (I haven't shown the `gdisk` output on the NVMe device, but it's got an `EF00` type code) is ready for use -- in fact, it's how this particular computer boots.

In any event, if your `/dev/sdb` has an ESP and if it uses FAT, then it's ready to go. If not, then you'll have to set up an ESP on the drive. That's a whole other issue, so I won't go into it here. Since you say the computer originally booted Windows 10, chances are it has an ESP, but I can't be certain of that, so you should check this detail.

Because your Ubuntu installation is using the ESP from `/dev/sda` now, you need to change that, and not just for the GRUB installation. You need to edit `/etc/fstab`: Find the line that defines `/boot/efi` and alter it to refer to the ESP on /dev/sdb, rather than the one on /dev/sda. For instance, your current `/etc/fstab` might have a line like the following:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6CB1-160F            /boot/efi            vfat    umask=0077  0  1
```

Note that in this example, the ESP is identified as having `UUID=6CB1-160F`, which is the same UUID code that `sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1` showed earlier. (Technically it's not a UUID, but that's another matter....) In your case, I'd expect the UUID to match what `blkid` shows as being on your `/dev/sda1`. Use the output of the `blkid` command on the ESP on `/dev/sdb` to find the UUID of that partition. For instance, suppose the new ESP's UUID is `66F7-FD24`. You'd edit the line in your `/etc/fstab` to read:

```
UUID=66F7-FD24            /boot/efi            vfat    umask=0077  0  1
```

Save the changes, type `sudo umount /boot/efi`, and then `sudo mount -a`. Your `/dev/sdb` ESP should now be mounted at `/boot/efi`, which you can verify with `df /boot/efi`:

```
$ df /boot/efi
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1         562080 14124    547956   3% /boot/efi
```

Your Linux installation has now mounted the ESP from `/dev/sdb` on `/boot/efi`; however, GRUB is still not installed there. Fortunately, that part is easy:

```
$ sudo grub-install
```

Under EFI, it's my understanding that `grub-install` ignores the device specification; instead, it installs GRUB to `/boot/efi` and sets up an EFI BootOrder variable to match. (A caveat: I use my own [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) on most of my computers, not GRUB 2, so I'm less familiar with the `grub-install` details, and I may be missing something. The documentation isn't exactly crystal-clear on this detail.)

You may want to use `efibootmgr` to verify the change. Type `sudo efibootmgr` and check that the first item in `BootOrder` is *not* the same as the `BootCurrent` line; but both of them should be `ubuntu` items. For instance, here's some output:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0006,0007,0008,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive
Boot0002* UEFI:Removable Device
Boot0003* UEFI:Network Device
Boot0004* ubuntu
Boot0006* UEFI OS
Boot0007* Hard Drive
Boot0008* CD/DVD Drive
```

In this example, the computer is currently booted through `Boot0000`, but it will boot next time through `Boot0004`. Both are `ubuntu` items, which point to GRUB 2 on the ESPs on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, respectively. You can add `-v` to the `efibootmgr` command to see more details, like this:

```
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,5f63fbfe-1a11-4ed8-80ff-13f1df6f04c0,0x800,0x114000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
```

The long string of hexadecimal numbers (`5f63fbfe-1a11-4ed8-80ff-13f1df6f04c0`) is a GUID, which should match the PARTUUID reported by `blkid`, as this one does for my computer's `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, shown earlier.

After rebooting to be sure it's working, if you want to be thorough about this, you can mount the ESP for your `/dev/sda` somewhere convenient (like `/mnt`) and delete the `EFI/ubuntu` directory on that partition. This will eliminate the duplicate GRUB 2 installation.