# Ubuntu not booting after initial restart/install

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

After installing Ubuntu on an external SSD, it asks to restart. When I do, it asks me to remove the installation media (the USB) that I installed linux with. After I do this and press enter, it skips booting from the SSD and boots windows instead. I have made sure the boot order prioritises the SSD over windows.
I have tried with 2 different laptops. Both have secure boot disable and fast boot disabled. Both have the boot order prioritising the SSD. The first computer, an HP, does not detect the SSD when I try to select a disk to boot from. The second computer, an Acer, does see it in the bios but does not boot from it (it just skips it and moves onto windows).

The  HP laptop doesn't have an option for AHCI. The Acer does, and it is enabled.

GParted can see the partitions of the SSD, and the first one (512MB) has the boot and esp flags. I can access the file system of the SSD, and it shows the default folders.

Any thoughts?

Specific information:

Version of ubuntu: 22.04 LTS https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
The second computer is an Acer i7-3537u, 2.0ghz, 4GB memory, 500TB HDD, with USB 3.0 and a nvidia geforce graphics card. Windows is installed on the HDD (I do not want to touch this HDD).

Comment: If not always booting from same system you used to install, you need to reinstall grub. Often easier with Boot-Repair. See this bug & manuy work arounds for when you install, but if you have ESP, you can just install grub in UEFI mode to external drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 &

Answer (score 0):

In the UEFI ( what some people still call BIOS ) choose 'boot from usb' as first option if the external disk is connected through usb.