# Why Ubuntu does not recognise external NVMe SSD to install on it?

Tags: system-installation, ssd

Good morning,

I would like to install Ubuntu on my external Samsung 980 Pro NVMe M.2 SSD.
On my MacBook I have used balenaEtcher to flash Ubuntu 22.04 to a 16 GB SanDisk USB drive.
After that I have restarted the laptop, held the option key and selected the usb drive.
Ubuntu Installation came up, when at drive management I chose 'Something different' but it only lists the Mac's internal ssd and the usb drive.

The Samsung SSD is recognised by any laptop I plug it into.
Currently it is formatted in NTFS by a windows machine.

Could someone please help me with the installation process?
There is not much information I could find online about this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which MacBook do you have? There are many that will not work correctly with any flavour of Linux ...

Comment: 13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports

Comment: Did Windows have fast start up on? That sets hibernation flag and prevents Linux NTFS driver from normally mounting it read write to prevent you from damaging it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation You must partition in advance to have an ESP on external drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, I formatted the SSD with my Mac using exFat, and I was able to install Ubuntu on it.
Thank you!