# Three-way boot, 2 drives: Ubuntu, Windows 10, SuSE Leap

Tags: system-installation, windows

I want to install Windows 10 on Drive 1 and Ubuntu/Suse Leap on Drive 2.  Drive 2, an add-on, is much larger than Drive 1. I don't need to preserve anything from my current system.

So I repartitioned Drive 1 as GPT and did a clean install of Windows 10 on Drive 1. I had Windows 10 running perfectly, though somehow the EFI partition ended up on Drive 2.  I next tried to install Ubuntu 22.04. The installation first aborted because it needed an EFI partition. I was able to fix that, but now grub-install aborts with "failed to get canonical path of `udev'". How can I get past this?

I don't mind throwing away installations as long as I can get the right end-result.

**Update 1:** A big part of the problem was something in the HP BIOS.  Unfortunately the main pointer to information on the HP BIOS, which I've been sent to several times, is both incomplete and badly out of date to the extent of being totally useless.

But casting about more or less blindly I managed to repair the BIOS and now Ubuntu is mostly working. I don't dare to investigate more thoroughly for fear of screwing it up again.

Comment: If you truly want them separate on a drive, best then to disconnect drive or in UEFI settings disable one drive. Windows ESP should be on Windows drive, but you must have had UEFI set to boot drive2 as default, so it used that. Ubuntu's Ubquity installer expects ESP on first drive, (not necessarily boot drive). https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 If not disconnecting drives, You will need an ESP on first drive.

Comment: Is the ESP partition the same thing as the EFI partition?

Comment: ESP=EFI System Partition

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to disable a drive via the boot settings, at lease not on my HP Pavilion.  I'd prefer not to open up the box.

Comment: How can I create an EFI partition in Ubiqiuty?  (I just learned that Ubiquity is the OS that I get when I try Kubuntu.)  gparted doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: With Ubiquity, it does not matter. It will want to find the ESP on first drive. Or if total erase of a drive, it creates an ESP. Best to use gparted to create ESP in advance. I have always used gparted to create a FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags. You can add/remove ESP or convert to plain FAT32 by adding or removing the flags. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator  And once UEFI entry created using GUID to find ESP, you can remove flags & it still will work, at least with some systems. Os-prober does not use flags.

Comment: I got past the problem with the EFI partition, but now I have a problem with a missing canonical path of udev (see revised description).

Comment: See  nfo in Update 1.