# Partitioning disk on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, mount

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 lts on a free partition of an external ssd disk. The ssd disk contains Linux Mint Vera. During the installation, at the section: Storage configuration: a message appears: "To continue you need to: Mount a file system at /".
What must I do to mount that partition in order to continue the installation?
My intention is to boot dually between Linux Mint and Ubuntu Server.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: If at Something Else install option where it shows partitions, you have to choose/change a partition and make it / (root). Normally you also select to format it. Note this bug for all external installs. Not sure if server installer still does this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 Note That while Mint not Ubuntu, it uses same grub & UEFI boot entry. You need to reset it as default, if desired as last install of grub will be the default.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!! I found rather complex to have both operating systems (Mint and Ubuntu Server on the external disk (selectting the partition during the installation of Ubuntu server). I thought to virtualize Ubuntu server on a partition of the disk. I shrinked a LM partition and installed VirtualBox. Trying to create the virtual machine, I message appears saying that: "it's not possible to create the folder of the machine. Check that the father folder exists and that you have permissions to create the folder of the machine". I can't copy files to the partition. I formatted it as ext4.

Comment: Doing an install in a VM has been on my list for years, just never gotten around to it. Did you give yourself ownership & permissions for the new partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types

Comment: Finally, I could install Ubuntu Server phisically on the partition, (not virtualized). The next step is to make it visible on Linux MInt Grub. Someone can help me?

Comment: Last install, is normally the grub in charge. `sudo update-grub` add entries, but you only have one default install & updating the other will not make any difference. Do you have both installs in same boot mode? Both UEFI?

Comment: Linux Mint is in UEFI mode. I don't know if Ubuntu Server is in UEFI or MBR  mode. US is installled on the partition and I can't boot it on the grub of Linux Mint.

Comment: You have to have both systems in same boot mode. If on same gpt partitioned drive, you can just reinstall grub in UEFI mode on server installs by chroot or use Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thank you ver much for the responses. Successfully, US boots and runs properly with LM. US appears in the grub. Lucky, the target is solved. Regards.