# strange output in efibootmgr

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mac, efibootmgr

I installed ubuntu on my macbook pro 2012, dual boot, with refind.

Ubuntu overwrited refind, and efibootmgr gives me strange input, including old things (like kali, but i've deleted and erased partition)

```
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0004,0003,0080,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* 瑰污Ȩ
Boot0002* 瑰污Ȩ
Boot0003* kali
Boot0004* Ð瑰污Ȩ
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Mac OS X
BootFFFF*
```

How can I clean this? I just want to have: refind (installed on mac)
then macos and ubuntu linux.

nothing more

Comment: Use efibootmgr & delete entries. You also should delete folders in ESP - efi system partition, but keep the folders you want to still use to boot with. Examples, but not exactly deleting kali. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem. What worked for me was removing the Chinese character boot entry and manually re-adding refind as a boot entry.

Here are the commands that I used.

```
efibootmgr -v
#at this point, check the numbers of the boot entries.

sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
sudo efibootmgr -b 0002 -B
sudo efibootmgr -b 0004 -B
#remove all of the Chinese character boot options. For you the boot numbers appear to be 0001, 0002, and 0004.

sudo nautilus /boot/efi
#this helped me determine the file path for refind on my system. In my case it was /boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi

df -h
#view all of your system partitions. You need to determine which partition on your system corresponds to /boot/efi

sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L refind -l /EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi
#you can type "man efibootmgr" for more information. You need to determine which partition on your system corresponds to /boot/efi and put the number of that partition after the -p option.

efibootmgr -v
#at this point, check the numbers of the boot entries. In my case refind was 0000 and ubuntu was 0001.

sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0001
```

For more information, see:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples