# Remove grub and windows bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a machine that came pre-installed with Windows.  I installed grub along with Ubuntu.  I would like to banish all trace of windows from the machine, and at the same time skip grub and just boot straight into linux.

This is a bit more than just a convenience.  I mainly use this machine headless, logging in remotely from a laptop using chrome remote desktop.  When I need to reboot the machine after updates, etc, having a step that requires user communication is an extra big pain.

How can I (1) remove the windows boot loader, and (2) remove grub?

Comment: Hi Steven, welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please tell us your computer model? Specifically, BIOS version, but the more details in general, the better.

Comment: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader You cannot remove grub as it is both boot menu & boot loader. If only Ubuntu, you should not see grub menu normally and can change settings in /etc/default/grub to 3 sec from default of 10, do not change to 0 as then if you need grub menu, you cannot get to it. Then run `sudo update-grub`