# Which of these partitions should I delete if my goal is to get rid of my Ubuntu dualboot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk

Recently I added Ubuntu as a dualboot on my Windows10 machine. I want to remove Ubuntu because I suspect I installed it in too wonky of a fashion and Ubuntu already is telling me I'm out of space.

Partition list- https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbSpF.png (Ignore the 86GB of unallocated space. That was done after installing Ubuntu)

Ubuntu screenshots of `df` command and System Monitor-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acfc3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ajz.png

Which partitions should I delete in order to remove Ubuntu off the disk, please?

Comment: You must delete sda12. However, partition numbers (12) are assigned at boot, at may change next boot. So be real sure it's correct.

Comment: If Ubuntu was last system installed, then it will be default boot. You have to first make sure system boots other install. Just removing partition still leaves grub's initial boot files which will not work without rest of grub that is in partition. If UEFI: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only need the first 3 partitions, can you make an image using clonezilla before you start deleting partitions?

This way a partition is removed that was needed you can restore the disk back to when it was working.