# Ubuntu dual-boot with windows 10 - unable to set grub as bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10, bootloader

I just installed Ubuntu alongside my windows 10. I cannot get it to boot, as in I cannot get grub to be the bootloader

I have been trying to get ubuntu on to a partition on my windows machine and I am having a hell of a time of it.
I tried once, goofed the install, cleared the partition, followed the top answer on this page [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader) to remove grub (I think this is where my problems started).

Then, I reinstalled ubuntu following this guide to the letter: [How To Install Ubuntu Along With Windows](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/).

I could not get it to boot back into ubuntu. When I hold delete on startup to get into the boot order settings, my main drive is just given as an option once and it says "windows boot loader." I loaded in to ubuntu using the live usb and ran boot repair, it did nothing. I used bcdedit to set the bootloader to grub by inputting this into the command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Restart just goes straight to windows. If I input `bcdedit` into the command prompt, it even says the boot manager path is going to grub/ubuntu:

[image]

I installed *hasleo easyuefi*. I can move the ubuntu thing up to the top of the list, restart (straight back into windows) now it's below windows again. Please will someone help I am at the end of my wits here.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Ubuntu on the hard drive in the machine and on the external I have mounted at this moment use the shimx64.efi to load their installs. Perhaps using this will get you a result in loading it.

```
root@zeus-H370M:~# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0005,0006
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9fad4e77-177d-4a3c-929a-3897e6bc1810,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0005* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,f2d84cb4-e597-4ac4-a2b2-10f0351c8784,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,91bafbe5-ebd9-452a-8e0a-c661d1ea976e,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\shimx64.efi)..BO
root@zeus-H370M:~# cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```