# I uninstalled Ubuntu 20.10, but it remains in my boot menu and selecting it brings me to GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

[Image of Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipCa4.jpg). CT1000 is my Windows drive and the Samsung SSD is the drive Ubuntu used to be installed on, now replaced with something else. As you can see, Ubuntu is still present, noting that it is installed on the CT1000 (the Windows drive) and selecting it brings me to GRUB.

How would I go about removing Grub and this Ubuntu option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Ubuntu install disk/usb and open `Terminal` then the `efibootmgr` to delete the entries not needed.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples

You can install it with in a live session on usb if it is not there, no clue on optical media never have tried to install a program on them, never use them anymore.

For the grub mount the drive in the live session and in the `EFI` directory there delete the ubuntu you see in it.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo rm -r /mnt/EFI/ubuntu
```

You may need to repair the windows boot loader too.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/

Be careful when removing the ubuntu directory that you have the correct `/dev/sd??`.

Comment: Follow-up: Your suggestion worked, but I choose to follow this guide https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader for removing the GRUB directly from Windows.

Comment: Good to read it worked, there is more than one way to do it with most of these things.