# My pc shows unknown filesystem after insmod normal and I don't have bootable window 7 USB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bios, grubrescue

[grub rescue error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj3pq.jpg)

I forcefully deleted my ubuntu partition and on rebooting it displays unknown filesystem.

Comment: If the partition you deleted controlled the booting of your machine, you need to boot *recovery media* for the OS that exists on the machine, and enter the appropriate commands to make it take ownership of the boot process. Ideally you do this before you delete the partition that controls boot (which means no recovery media is required).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Are you trying to remove Ubuntu and go back to Windows, repair Ubuntu (unlikely being as you deleted it), or reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step1 > create a bootable USB of your Linux distribution which you forcefully deleted In   my case ubuntu 16.04.

Step2 > reinstall that distribution,and if yo want to uninstall it do it with proper steps.

(if your PC does not detect the bootable USB then do as follow)

step3 > GO to your PC's BIOS and go to boot setting.

step4 > Change the boot priority of your USB to 1 by clicking on "+"or"-".

step5> restart your PC and install your OS, after installing restart your PC and again change your boot priority to hard disk. this will solve your problem.

(Note:- you don't need to upgrade your GRUB ans it will be done automatically while installing your OS.)