# Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I wanted to delete Linux from Windows10 dual boot. I deleted the Linux partition, then I fixed windows bootloader by using a windows10 bootable USB: Repair your computer>troubleshoot>Command Prompt > "bootrec.exe /fixmbr". Now, I am stuck at the GNU GRUB version 2.04 screen when I turn my laptop with no response from the keyboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to get into your BIOS on startup which depends on your model it's one of the F keys on top. Likely F2 or F8, go to the section titled boot or boot devices and move Windows Bootloader higher than Ubuntu. This should make it where your computer will boot Windows by default and you can use the partitioning tools inside of Windows from there to grow your partition back. Search what key to enter your BIOS for your laptop brand. You can also disable Ubuntu from booting on that menu to prevent GRUB from being able to load at all.

Note that this method will not remove GRUB from your system, it will simply allow Windows to boot again.