# How to completely remove GRUB on a dual-boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

solution: ([Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader))

(I can still easily access my Windows 11 OS by hitting f12 repeatedly and selecting windows boot loader)

Last night, I rebooted my pc and was greeted with the dreaded xxx/xxx blocks message an a black screen. I couldn't find a fix that worked for me online, so I decided to just delete my Ubuntu partition (like an idiot) I then proceeded to reinstall Ubuntu (via universal usb loader bc I don't own a usb) I then restarted my pc and was just greeted with the grub terminal. How do I completely remove GRUB loader

Comment: You will get better and faster help if you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1388981/edit) instead of using comments to clarify your goal.