# How can I stop the grub command line appearing on startup after deleting Ubuntu and boot directly to Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently have deleted Ubuntu now whenever I boot the grub line command appears, I was able to boot into windows using the following commands

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod chain
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
```

The problem is I have to do this each time I boot

I tried messing with the diskpart tho wasn't able to fully manage and solve it due to my lack of knowledge of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: I dont seem to have the Ubuntu one avaible might be cause I deleted it from disk managent
https://prnt.sc/j1jX9sx0tdVv

Comment: The fallback boot entry or drive entry uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. That file can be either a copy of shimx64.efi or Windows efi boot file. You may need to copy Windows /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi  to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in the ESP - efi system partition.