# Windows Boot Manager fails without GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Laptop model: HP pavilion gaming 15.6 EC2xxx (RTX 3050 mobile, AMD Ryzen 7 5800H)

In conjunction with another problem where Ubuntu 23.04 freezes midboot. I decided to erase Ubuntu entirely off my drive. This forced me to boot into Windows via the GRUB command line. This works, but it's cumbersome to have to type in those commands every time.

I decided to delete the GRUB bootloader by the instructions listed here: [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

but then as I rebooted, my laptop entered a boot loop where it would show "Reset System" on the screen for a split second, go black, and then do it again. I decided to use an Ubuntu installation to get GRUB back, and selecting windows boot manager from GRUB does work, but selecting it from the BIOS menu just says "Reset System" yet again and returns me to GRUB.

so now I have an issue where I'm stuck between a Linux installation that sometimes will not boot, and a Windows installation that will not boot if the half-broken Linux installation is not present, despite not depending on it at all.

I think I would need to restore the EFI System partition to its factory state, but I'm unsure how. Any way to do this without destroying my windows partition?

Comment: try this methods https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-bootloader-linux/

Comment: Boot-Repair can only install a Windows type BIOS boot loader. For UEFI boot you have to run the Windows repairs from Windows or your Windows repair/recovery flash drive. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restoring-windows-efi-files-without-wiping-linux/a2e46763-dac0-4541-bbc8-af0085cb67a9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)