# Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader - EFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a system that's currently set up with a dual-boot configuration of Linux and Windows, managed by the GRUB bootloader on EFI. I deleted the Linux partition, but I didn't take proper steps to remove GRUB. However, I now want to uninstall GRUB and revert to using only the Windows bootloader for EFI. I'm seeking guidance on the proper steps to safely uninstall GRUB and ensure that the Windows bootloader takes over as the default option for booting.

If anyone has experience with this process or can provide step-by-step instructions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Boot your windows recovery media & use the tools it provides for this purpose. The commands vary on version of windows (*you didn't give details*).

Comment: I am not able to restart the pc, everytime i restart, it boots ubuntu ( which doesn't exist) and so grub cli loads up

Comment: Note, you should always be able to use the EFI menu (some key at power-up to allow you to select device or OS (windows) to boot).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: Yes, that could be done, but it is annoying to do that everytime i start my system. Moreover, when i restart my pc ( in windows ), it brings me back to grub.