# Dual boot with Windows without grub bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, uefi

I have Windows 11 installed and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have had some experience with some Linux Distros, but not that much.

I know after installation, I will be prompted with the grub boot loader every time I turn my laptop on. Is there a way to avoid this? If there is, how can I boot in Ubuntu without it? Are there alternatives, instead of the grub boot loader? And what can i customize and change with it?

Also, I am not directly asking not to have it. What are the pros and cons? And if I want to remove the Linux completely, will I need to use windows installation media to remove the grub2?

Comment: Grub is the default boot loader of *modern* Ubuntu, but there are alternatives (with some architectures only somewhat recently switching to grub; whilst others have always used it). You don't need to use windows media to remove grub's control; windows has commands to do that; but if you forget to run that before deleting grub or a partition that controls booting then windows media is required (*ie. because user forgot a step*)

Comment: If newer system with UEFI boot, you should always be able to boot from UEFI one time boot menu. That is same menu you use to select to boot the live installer flash drive. You can set Windows as first in boot order and only boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu. Grub is both boot menu & boot loader. You can remove or not add Windows to grub menu and it will by-pass menu & boot directly to Ubuntu if only one Ubuntu install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)