# Does installing Ubuntu overwrite windows bootloader?

Tags: boot, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader)

So there's the question. I want to preserve my original Windows 7 Loader.

Comment: See this answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader to keep your bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Wubi maybe the easiest way to go, but it will make your Ubuntu 'part of windows'.

The upside is: you can easily uninstall it just like any windows program.

The downside: its just slightly slower and a touch less stable then if you install Ubuntu on its own drive or partition, outside of windows.

But, as you guessed, the Ubuntu installer (grub2) will mess up your Windows bootloader.
However, to avoid that is easy: the trick is to place the Ubuntu bootloader in its own boot partition, instead of it modifying the one from windows. Follow the link that Rick Green added below your question.

A very good step by step description how to do this, is [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/).

Answer (score 0):

Install using WUBI. It keeps the Windows bootloader.