# Install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 (not preinstalled) without grub

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, 64-bit, windows-8, mbr

I want to install x64 Ubuntu 12.04.2 on my HP laptop. I don't like grub, so I want to install without it or install grub onto another partition and then add grub to Windows' bootloader (and set grub timeout to 0) . Is that possible and if yes, how can that be done?

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's](http://askubuntu.com/a/62442/117893) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VMWare Player and load the iso. You can have a look at the youtube video below.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOLkW7s9k1Q

For dual boot with windows and ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Installing ubuntu within windows

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Comment: but that's virtualisation. It probably won't run x64 systems and will be slow like virtualbox is

Comment: it does depend on your system configuration also. I have installed the same and i don't see any slowness. I have sonyvaio vpcsb37gg lappy with i5 intel on it

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu normally, remove grub, reinstall Windows' bootloader again and install grub to a different partition and add grub to Windows' bootloader

Comment: He didn't ask how to dual-boot Ubuntu nor how to have it in a VM, he asked if he could have Ubuntu and Windows but not use the GRUB bootloader and `add grub to Windows' bootloader`. As I mentioned, the exact answer to this is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader/62442#62442).

Comment: @Alex agreed i missed the point.

Comment: @Alex I could do that if I knew how not to install GRUB to the MBR

Comment: In the Debian installer there's an option for that, there should be one in Ubuntu's installer too, I think it's under the manual partitioning section. Anyway, you can just [install GRUB to a partition](http://superuser.com/questions/187586/how-do-i-install-grub-to-a-partiton-and-not-mbr) and then use the same tool found in the answer I linked to replace the current MBR (GRUB) with Window's MBR and then create an entry on it for GRUB (GRUB will be in the partition you installed it to).