# Installed Ubuntu 13.04 on Windows 7 but it loads straight into Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot

As you can already tell, I am a Ubuntu newbie...trying to make the big switch from Windows to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a partition aside from Windows. I was waiting for a prompt to ask me which OS to choose from but when I started my computer, Ubuntu loaded up automatically. I would like to have the option of choosing the loaders on Windows (white font, black background) and not the Ubuntu one (white font, purple background).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see the choice of Ubuntu and Windows 7 in white font purple background when the computer boots?

Comment: So you want to use 'Windows boot loader' instead of 'Grub'? [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](http://askubuntu.com/q/62440/37006).

Answer (score 0):

Can explain a little more in detail what you mean "Ubuntu loaded up automatically" step-by-step.

It sounds a first glance that you may need repair you GRUB bootloader or simply re-install it.

Go on this page https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub and read under **"How-to"**.

Answer (score 0):

Open Dash (the ubuntu icon at the top of the bar on the left), search for "Terminal" and open it. Type in `sudo update-grub` there will be a prompt asking for password, just enter your user's password. After you reboot there will be a list of available operating systems, Ubuntu at the top, Windows at the bottom.

For more information about `update-grub` or any other command run in terminal `man <command>` where command==any package like `update-grub` or anything other program.

Welcome to Linux.