# Unify Windows and Ubuntu boot managers

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I ran into some trouble trying to start Ubuntu 14 in a new laptop with Windows 8.1 preinstalled. However, the booting process is kind of uncomfortable now.

When I start the laptop first I can see the Windows boot manager with Windows 8.1 as the only option. Then, I found out that pressing `esc` leads to grub, and then I can run Ubuntu. I don't know how this happened, but after hours trying to be able to start Ubuntu unsuccessfuly now I am more than happy.

So now I just want to have both options (and future options) in the same boot manager, I honestly don't care if it's the Windows boot manager or grub.

I tried following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/62442/252219) but it didn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: EasyBCD is not required for UEFI boot. And it may just complicate things. But did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode or BIOS mode. UEFI and BIOS boot are not compatible and once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub only boots systems in same boot mode. And then you can only boot from UEFI boot menu and choose either BIOS or UEFI boot. Boot-Repair can convert a BIOS install to UEFI. Do not reinstall Ubuntu unless you use Something Else as it may just erase everything.

Comment: I installed it in BIOS mode, I changed UEFI for legacy

Comment: If Windows is UEFI and Ubuntu BIOS, the only way you can boot is from UEFI menu or perhaps one time boot key (often f12, but varies). Some auto switch and others may require you to turn on legacy/CSM/BIOS to boot Ubuntu and turn that off and turn on UEFI to boot Windows. Some also have UEFI and BIOS setting as option (not one or other) to make it auto switch.

Answer (score 0):

Try following instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231(v=vs.85).aspx 
That will add Ubuntu to the Windows Boot Manager and you should able to switch between Windows and Ubuntu fairly easily.

This is an error you might get from going into Ubuntu from Windows Boot Manager and how to fix it [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Windows boot manager cannot boot/chainload Ubuntu/or any Linux/ in UEFI mode.

The other way around works - GRUB can chainload Windows boot manager but not in this case of mixed BIOS/UEFI mode.

Typing ESC on display of Windows UEFI boot manager causes return to firmware UEFI which on OP's computer loads MBR=GRUB (Ubuntu installed in BIOS/legacy mode on GPT disk).

A diagnostic output of Boot Repair would give more information on MBR/boot sectors and partition contents.

You should repair Ubuntu's boot to UEFI.
Do not touch Windows UEFI booting.

@dabadaba, 
the thread you followed is complete nonsense (Windows UEFI installation and MBR+EasyBCD ???)- I think it has to deleted (at the moment it is protected ?!) as it would bring harm to other people searching for help in forum.