# Can I use GRUB only when I want to use ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I've installed windows 10 already, but the time to install ubuntu is coming.

I usually don't need ubuntu, as I just use Ubuntu to use Tensorflow..
so, the 'GRUB' is very annoying thing to me.

I don't want to see GRUB everytime I push my power butten.

I want to use GRUB when I want to use ubuntu.
When I don't need ubuntu, I want to boot windows 10 without seeing grub.

help me..

p.s
Thanks for your help!!

after I read your answers and comments, I think i should have written more info about my computer.

I use two disk.

ssd : windows 10 drive

hhd : drive for data storage(and ubuntu will be here. I'll shrink this volume to install ubuntu)

Comment: You can set Windows as the default OS in grub and make grub hidden. There are lot's of answers with directions.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, just set Windows as default and when you want Ubuntu go into one time boot key like f10 or f12 and choose the ubuntu entry. If BIOS install grub2's boot loader to sdb drive and in BIOS choose to boot sdb drive if you want Ubuntu.

Comment: You can set `GRUB_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/default/grub`. It is very easy.

Comment: @Pilot6   Oh, that is another solution. but, though i can't see grub. grub will work. right?

Comment: @oldfred  UEFI. my system is UEFI.   you mean, I must install ubuntu seperately from windows. right? and when i install ubuntu, the bootloader would be in ubutu drive?

Comment: grub will work. When you need it, you can call it by Shift or ESC and boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: With UEFI all systems install boot loaders into the ESP - efi system partition. And UEFI is a boot manager that lets you choose which system to boot from ESP. Grub is both a boot manager with menu & boot loader. With Ubuntu whether UEFI or BIOS you always install grub to drive like sda or sdb. And with UEFI grub actually only installs into the ESP on drive seen as sda. So you can just choose to boot Ubuntu from UEFI when you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  When you want to boot to Windows, make the change in your computer's BIOS for Windows to be the primary Boot option.

When you want to boot to Ubuntu or have the choice of Windows or Ubuntu, then make `Ubuntu` your primary boot option in you BIOS.

Using `Ubuntu` to presented with the Choice is most likely the best way to go.

Also, there are many ways you can customize the way Grub Looks and how it behaves.  But the first thing you see is a black screen with a choice of which OS you want to go into.

**Update:**

After the comments below, I find that Windows Boot Manager can boot Linux.  Ubuntu will have to be on a separate drive for this to work, but you can take a look at this answer:
[Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/a/62442/29012)

After installing Ubuntu on a different drive, use [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to add the functionally of as they say on their site **Dual-boot awith anything you want**.

Comment: This is possible when using UEFI or when OSes are located on separate disks. Instead of setting up BIOS it is easier to use the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: @Pilot6 Should I create a new question or is it possible you can add the method here.  I wasn't aware that Windows Boot Manager had that ability.  I'll continue to research, if I find it, I'll test it locally and add the information to my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I do not recommend to use Windows bootloader to boot Ubuntu, but it is possible. I did that for fun.

Comment: @karel Thanks.  I understood the question.  I tried to be specific to the question.  I wasn't aware the Windows Boot Manager could launch Linux.  I gave the only way I know how to go straight into Windows without seeing Grub and how to go into Ubuntu when it time to go into Ubuntu.  I think it's great that Microsoft may be adding support for booting into alternate OS's via their Boot Manager.

Comment: That support has been added by MS very long ago ;-)

Comment: If i change the bootloader to hdd(I use ssd for windows) when I install ubuntu. I can do what i want? I mean, When I want to use windows10 -> push power button to boot windows 10 directly without seeing grub.         When I want to use ubuntu -> enter the Bios boot menu

Comment: @RayleighKim Yes.  The link suggests using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) from Windows to add the functionality.

Comment: @Pilot6 I finally got around to testing EasyBCD so that I could provide the steps for this functionality.  When I first start it up `EasyBCD` it detect the computer as being EFI and advises it won't work.  The `Add Menu` comes up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a straight answer because there's a fundamental issue with the propositions implied in your question (see below).

What you can do:

- Use different boot loader than Grub. Some possible alternatives are the one included with your BIOS or Windows.
- Have Grub default to one boot menu entry after some time when you don't press any keys until then. You can even hide the boot menu and only show a black (or whatever colour you want) screen unless you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while Grub waits.

What you cannot do:

- Have the boot loader “know” which boot entry you want to choose unless you happen to always want to boot the same entry. The only way to not have to choose is to restrict the set options to one.