# Dual boot options not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 8.1 and after 3 to 4 times, it worked properly. But after it starts, it directly boots to the Windows boot manager then Windows.

It does not show the bootloader to choose any other OS!

Any help please?

Comment: Did you change the boot order to boot GRUB first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader)

Comment: Can you still manually boot from UEFI boot menu? Windows 8 & 10 resets itself to first in boot order on updates. Grub also resets itself to first in boot order if you reinstall grub. Can you also reset boot order in your UEFI boot menu - boot tab? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

restart your computer, and before it switches to Windows, press the button that opens the BIOS options, then go to the boot tab and set Ubuntu to be on the top of the boot list, then save and exit..
Once Ubuntu starts, install the grub using :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub2 -y
sudo update-grub2
```

This should solve your problem, as it solved mine.