# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 without GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have two SSDs in my PC, one with an existing Windows 10 installation and another I just added that I plan to install Ubuntu on.

The ask:
How to install Ubuntu without GRUB. I want to keep Windows 10 as the default and when I want to boot into Ubuntu, I do it via my BIOS boot menu by selecting the Ubuntu SSD.

I read here that manually setting the GRUB timeout to 0 doesn't work because it resets if more than one OS is detected.

Also, if I decide to remove the Ubuntu SSD in the future I dont want to have to repair Windows to get the Windows Boot Loader back. So I'm trying to avoid installing GRUB entirely.

Any suggestions? Besides just using a VM? :p

Much appreciated.

Comment: ...and what will boot Ubuntu if Grub isn't installed? Just selecting it from the BIOS is obviously not enough.

Comment: you always need a boot manager to boot Ubuntu and another to boot Windows 10, then they can call one another. your question should probably be how to select a default one

Comment: Doesn't GRUB replace the Windows Boot Manager when Ubuntu is installed alongside Windows 10? In that case, is it safe to assume that grub will be installed on the Ubuntu SSD, so that if I physically remove the SSD from my PC, Windows will continue to boot normally without any repairs needed?

Comment: @FahadAl-Riyami Only if you tell Ubuntu to install GRUB to the same drive as windows during the installation.  Might be safer to pull your Windows drive before the installation so that it doesn't accidentally overwrite the Windows bootloader.  Myself, I don't use the automatic part of the installer, I always choose the something else and manually setup my drives, then choose the appropriate drive for where GRUB is going to be installed.

Comment: If you search you find a fix to OS Prober so hidden menu and  timeout=0 works. I think Heeymena (spelling?) wrote an answer about a year ago.

Comment: @Terrance, I will try pulling the Windows drive first and then install Ubuntu. Then change the boot order and see how that works.

Comment: You should be able to install grub only to the Ubuntu partition/drive, and let Windows manage the MBR, see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, removing the Windows drive then installing Ubuntu on the secondary drive is the way to go.

After installing Ubuntu, put the Windows drive back in and change the boot order in the BIOS to whichever drive/OS you want to boot first. Then you can boot into the secondary drive/OS using the BIOS boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the intended use case for grub annoyingly. The only option is to disable any drive for which you do not want the Master Boot Record (MBR) to be affected during the ubuntu installation.

Alternatively back up the MBR on each other drive you have attached before installation, and then after installation use the backups on any drive other than the one with Ubuntu installed. You can do this with with a variety of partitioning tools and a quick google brought these up depending on the current operating system you have on those drives:

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html

https://opensource.com/article/18/7/how-use-dd-linux

Be cautious when using linux tools to backup/recover windows drives/disks as this may have unintended consequences! The phyiscal drive removal seems a lot easier unless there are other caveats, for example some laptop's warranty is removed when opened. You may be able to disable some of your drives from the bios setup menus.

Ubuntu's grub is a life saver for having dual boot on the same drive, and you can't really do dual-boot without it as far as I know. However it has a major flaw when using dual-boot across multiple drives as you pointed out, and I hope you have found some answers here.