# Installing 18.04 without Grub

Tags: grub2, 18.04, refind

Is there a way to install 18.04 without the grub?
I will use clover or `rEFInd` to boot, instead.

Comment: As you plan to use UEFI there is no problem with installing both boot-loaders, they will share the EFI System Partition, each boot-loader in it's own folder. You only need to adjust the boot order in UEFI settings to boot with rEFInd.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048300/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-without-grub See the comments especially.